# limit of a function with competing terms

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, limits, continuity

I am trying to solve the following problem:

$\lim_{a \to \infty} y(a)$, where $ y(a)=\int_{0}^{\theta(a)} \dfrac{f(\lambda)}{(a-\lambda)^2}d\lambda$, and $\theta(a)$ is a linearly increasing function which is less than $a$.

By plotting it, I can see that $y(a)$ converges to zero as $a$ increases, however, I do not know how to show it analytically.

Can I say that as $a$ increases the upper limit of integral increases linearly and at the same time the denominator of the integrant increases quadratically. So, when $a$ is large enough, $O(\frac{1}{a^2})$ overtakes $O(a)$ and $y$ approaches to zero?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What’s $f$? If you were able to plot I am assuming  that you have an explicit formula for $f$ or at least some conditions.

Comment: $f$ is $\lambda$ multiplied by a Gaussian distribution, $f(\lambda) = \lambda N(\lambda; \mu, \sigma)$.